# How can I add styling to an element in React?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

In normal JavaScript you can grab an element by its id and add a style to it.
For example:

```
var element = document.getElementById("myElement");
element.style.backgroundColor = "#f5f5f5";
```

My question is how you can do this in react. Is it even possible to add this style?
In react im using onChange in a function outside the render(). I looked at the React DOM for styling and tried but since styling is in different function it will tell me how the variable is undefined.
this is my code:

```
ChangeImage() {
        var imgStyles = {
            backgroundColor: '#000',
            padding: 5,
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="class">
                <div className="img-surround">
                <img 
                    src={this.state.file} 
                    id="img" 
                     style={imgStyles}/>
                </div>
```

Everything is working except styles and I even tried putting in different functions

Comment: react docs is a wonderful place, full of examples, and the documentation is really well done. your questions look really base use cases, which are fully covered there and can be learned just through a first easy read to the doc. I would suggest you spend some time there while doing your react experiments!

Comment: You shouldn't be manipulating the DOM directly. Follow the docs and take a data-driven approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to render the element with the style you can return the element like this in a react functional component:

```
return <div style={{backgroundColor: "#f5f5f5"}}></div>
```

If you want the element to only have that style in a certain condition you can use the useState hook in a react functional component:

```
const [myState, setMyState] = useState(false);
return <div style={myState && {backgroundColor: "f5f5f5"}}></div>
```

And you should change myState's value using setMyState however you like. For example:

```
const [myState, setMyState] = useState(false);
return <div onClick={() => myState ? setMyState(true) : setMyState(false)} style={myState && {backgroundColor: "f5f5f5"}}></div>
```

In this example whenever you click on the div the style is added or removed by case

Comment: is this possible with onChange function?

Comment: Of course, just change 'onClick' with 'onChange'